# On the fixed-point iteration

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Suppose we are trying to solve $x^4 - \sin( \pi x /2) = 0$ by fixed point iteration $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ for suitable $g(x)$  a starting guess $x_0 = 1.1$ Will it succed in finding the root $x=1$ if $g(x) = \dfrac{ \sin (\pi x / 2 ) }{x^3}$?

Well, one way to tell is if the root $r \in [a,b]$ and if $|g(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then fixed point iteration converges for all starting point $x \in [a,b]$.

So, my idea is to to choose an interval containing the root x=1 and the starting point $x_0 =1.1$. For example, we can take $[1,2]$ and we know

$$ g'(x) = \frac{ \pi x \cos( \pi x /2) - 6 \sin (\pi x /2) }{x^4}$$ we have  $|g(x)| \leq |\pi x \cos( \pi x /2) - 6 \sin (\pi x /2) | $ since $\frac{1}{x^4} \leq 1$ on $[1,2]$. Now, Im having some difficulties in bounded the last expression so as to obtain the bound of $1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing a factor $2$ from the denominator of the derivative, per [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+sin(pi*x%2F2)%2Fx%5E3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we just evaluate the derivative (supplying the missing factor $2$ in the denominator) at $x=1$ we get $g'(x)|_{x=1}=-3$

You can do fixed point iteration but need to find a different formulation.  As $\sin \left(\frac {\pi x}2 \right)$ is flat at $x=1$ my thought would be 
$$x=\left(\sin \left(\frac {\pi x}2 \right)\right)^{1/4}$$

Starting with $1.1$ two iterations got to $0.999997$ and two more got to $1$ within the accuracy of my spreadsheet.

Comment: I see, so it wont find the root $x=1$

Comment: That is right.  Unless you start right there (or accidentally hit it) when you are close the next guess is three times as far away.

Comment: how about if we Newton;s method instead>

Comment: You can do fixed point, but just need to find a different iteration.  As $\sin \frac {\pi x}2$ is flat at $x=1$ my thought would be $x=\left(\sin \frac {\pi x}2\right)^{1/4}$  Its first derivative is $0$ there, so you will converge very quickly.  Two iterations got me to $0.999997$ and a fourth nailed it in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment.*

If you use Newton method for finding the zero of
$$f(x)=x^4-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)$$ starting with $x_0=1.1$, you will get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.1000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.0144640865676508848 \\
 2 & 1.0003650875077377200 \\
 3 & 1.0000002408222162678 \\
 4 & 1.0000000000001048802 \\
 5 & 1.0000000000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$ Nice convergence, no overshoot of the solution.

Now, suppose that you use $x_0=0.9$; the problem will be quite different
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.90000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.0241776781772581515 \\
 2 & 1.0009966763457768217 \\
 3 & 1.0000017919396538515 \\
 4 & 1.0000000000058069133 \\
 5 & 1.0000000000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$ This is related to Darboux theorem; you will converge smoothly if yous start at a poinf $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) >0$. This was the case for the first example but not for the second.

As Ross Millikan answered, if you look instead for the zero of function
$$g(x)=x-\sqrt[4]{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)}$$ for each of the above cases, you would have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.1000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.0029268046440802235 \\
 2 & 1.0000026372829963012 \\
 3 & 1.0000000000021451740 \\
 4 & 1.0000000000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.90000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.0033137508866509540 \\
 2 & 1.0000033799192375030 \\
 3 & 1.0000000000035233964 \\
 4 & 1.0000000000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$